# How can I ignore repeated use of a keycode?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I want to happen in my code if the user has typed a letter: That letter must not repeat.

In my case I'm using a keycode and an `if`-`else` statement. Is there a way to make it only one key press that each letter *one* time?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #Ans_container {
      margin-left: 37%;
      margin-bottom: 350px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="del();">
  <div id="Ans_container"></div>
  <script>
    function typing(x) {

      if (x.keyCode == 65) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "A";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 66) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "B";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 67) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "C";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 68) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "D";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 69) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "E";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 70) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "F";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 71) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "G";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 72) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "H";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 73) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "I";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 74) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "J";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 75) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "K";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 76) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "L";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 77) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "M";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 78) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "N";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 79) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "O";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 80) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "P";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 81) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "Q";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 82) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "R";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 83) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "S";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 84) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "T";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 85) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "U";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 86) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "V";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 87) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "W";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 88) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "X";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 89) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "Y";
      }
      if (x.keyCode == 90) {
        document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += "Z";
      }
    }
    document.onkeydown = typing;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a list of characters which have already been "seen".   When a new character arrives, check if it's already in the list. If not, ignore it.

You can also save a lot of typing by using [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) instead of 26 `if` statements.

```js
var seen = {};

function typing(x) {
  if ((x.keyCode >= 65) && (x.keyCode <= 90)) {
    var st = String.fromCharCode(x.keyCode);

    if (!seen[st]) {
      document.getElementById('Ans_container').innerHTML += st;
      seen[st] = true;
    }
  }
}

document.onkeydown = typing;
```

```css
#Ans_container {
  margin-left: 37%;
  margin-bottom: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Ans_container"></div>
```

Comment: Thx mate idk there is a simple way to do this. I take me time to type all those if else statements

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #Ans_container {
      margin-left: 37%;
      margin-bottom: 350px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="del();">
  <div id="Ans_container"></div>
  <script>
    var Done = ' '; // the empty list of pressed keys
    function typing(x) {
      
      var curVal = String.fromCharCode(x.keyCode);
          // we look the position of curVal in Done
          // if it is not in ( === -1 ) we continue
          //      |                    
          //      |                       if keyCode is between 64 and 91
          //      |                              we continue
          //      |                                    |
          //      v                                    v
      if (Done.indexOf(curVal)===-1 && (x.keyCode > 64 && x.keyCode < 91) ) {
          document.getElementById("Ans_container").innerHTML += curVal;
          Done += curVal + ' '; // we add curVal in the list of pressed keys.
      }
    }
    document.onkeydown = typing;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way would be to change your `eventListener` from `document.onkeydown` to `document.onkeyup`. The issue that you are having is that when a user holds down the key, your event listener is fired for every DOM digest cycle. The `document.onkeyup` listener is the easiest way to separate you from this simple error. If you would like to further prevent any repetition of characters, I would suggest that you use @PaulRoub's very simple answer.

While @PaulRoub's answer will solve your issue single-handedly, the simple change I am suggesting will greatly increase your performance and I believe that it is an absolute must.

I would also suggest changing your event listener to `document.addEventListener('keyup', typing, true)` as it is now the standard method of attaching event listeners and does not overide your `documents` `onkeyup` attribute.

I have coppied @PaulRoub's snippet and have applied my changes to it.

```js
var seen = {};

function typing(x) {
  if ((x.keyCode >= 65) && (x.keyCode <= 90)) {
    var st = String.fromCharCode(x.keyCode);

    if (!seen[st]) {
      document.getElementById('Ans_container').innerHTML += st;
      seen[st] = true;
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', typing, true);
```

```css
#Ans_container {
  margin-left: 37%;
  margin-bottom: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Ans_container"></div>
```